# ASP.Net DataPager doesn't work without QueryStringField

Tags: asp.net, listview, datapager

I'm currently working on a control for my SharePoint webpart that makes use of a ListView and a DataPager. I've seen a dozen of tutorials demonstrate data paging without setting  the QueryStringField property, but I can't seem to replicate the same results. The pager seems to be able to divide/page my datasource (which is a List object) properly but clicking on any of the datapager's fields doen't change the listview's page number. It also appears that the listview's PagePropertiesChanged and PagePropertiesChanging events won't trigger unless I call the SetPageProperties method.

I did try specifying the QueryStringField to something, and with that, I'm able to navigate through the pages, but I'd rather not do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to enable viewstate if you want to use it without querystring field

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
protected void ListView1_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
    DataPager1.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
    ListView1.DataSource = productList;
    ListView1.DataBind();
    DataPager1.DataBind();
}
```